# Company Name reservation justification

Tags: incorporation, pakistan

I applied for name reservation and incorporation of company here in Pakistan, suggested name got reserved but it does not have any meaning nor is a dictionary word and I selected it because the domain name was available for registration and company registration is mainly for e-commerce services, I have been asked:

> Proper meaning/significance/justification and relevance of proposed name
> is required. Please add any object related word in the proposed name.

What can I do to resolve my issue? I really like this name and it got approved.

Answer (score 1):

Simply truthfully describe the facts by saying, for example:

> The proposed name is a nonsense word with no known pre-existing
> meaning or significance or relevance. The proposed name was chosen whimsically because it
> is distinctive and sounds nice. There is no object related word in the
> proposed name.

I suspect that the main reasons for the requirement are to limit use of names that are purely descriptive, or that have obscene or blasphemous meanings that may be concealed with an alternative spelling or a metaphor, or fraudulently imitate existing businesses.